# Не могу вывести видео с компьютера

Tags: reactjs, next.js

У меня есть видео в корневой папке `pes.mp4`, я хочу его выводить на странице, но мне выдает такую ошибку:

> *GET http://localhost:3000/pes.mp4 404 (Not Found)*

```
export default function Home() {
 return (
  <div className={styles.wrapper}>
    <video controls>
      <source src="../pes.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <Head>
      <title>title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    </Head>
  </div>
);
}
```

[image: Папка с проектом]

Comment: Извините, у меня довольно очевидный вопрос: а что будет, если в ссылке на файл не делать переход в корневую директорию, то есть, написать  <source src="pes.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> ?

Comment: Сейчас проверил и не изменилось ничего

Comment: А в какой код рендерится всё на странице? может, там по коду станет понятно, в чем проблема?

Comment: `
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

   function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
     return (
       <Layout>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
       </Layout>
       )
      }

   export default MyApp
`

Comment: Ну попробуйте тогда явно /pes.mp4 - вы же не указываете, какая страница загружается при обращении к localhost?

Comment: /pes.mp4 - не помогло. Страницу не указываю, открывается просто домашняя(localhost)

Comment: Попробуйте положить видео в папку, до которой у вас указан статический путь. И соответственно изменить ссылку.

Comment: Создал папку в проекте и попробовал менять путь в src, но всё равно никак не получается

Comment: "домашняя" - это какая? Где лежит относительно корня сайта, относительно того самого видео-файла?

Comment: Я затрудняюсь ответить, но "домашняя" - это же index.js(http://localhost:3000/). index.js находится в паке pages, а папка с видео находится на уровне с pages. Мне сложно точно ответить на вопрос

Comment: Ну так положите видео в pages, раз это и есть корень сайта. И укажите /pes.mp4.

Comment: Попробовал, но не помогло